# Setting up port forwarding on router to serve apache on a Mac

Tags: mac, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding

I have setup port forwarding on my router to Mac. When I try I enter my IP address the browser just times out and my router just resets.

Now when I port forward to my NAS server everything works fine and the web page is served.

I want to get the port forwarding working properly so Mac acts as a web server (firewall is disabled on Mac) and also when I enter:

> sudo ipfw list

I have port 80 allowed.

When using an online service to check that port 80 is open for some reason the router restarts (didn't do that when changed port forwarding to my Nas server, it worked fine).

Not sure if this will help but I checked my logs on the router and I get the following pls ignore the initial time on the logs, not sure why it did that but I cleared the logs and the tried to access my Mac and this is the log:

```
Jan  1 00:00:30 localhost syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.18.5
Jan  1 00:00:30 localhost user.info syslog: disable write rom conf.
Jan  1 00:00:34 localhost user.err syslog: silex/smbd.c:smbd_main(942)
Jan  1 00:00:34 localhost user.err syslog:   smbd version 3.0.34 started.
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog: printing/pcap.c:pcap_cache_reload(159)
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog:   Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog: printing/pcap.c:pcap_cache_reload(159)
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog:   Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog: silex/nmbd.c:nmbd_main(723)
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog:   Netbios nameserver version 3.0.34 started.
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog: passdb/pdb_smbpasswd.c:startsmbfilepwent(241)
Jan  1 00:00:35 localhost user.err syslog:   startsmbfilepwent_internal: file /usr/local/samba/private/smbpasswd did not exist. File successfully created.
Jan  1 00:00:37 localhost daemon.notice pppd[918]: pppd 2.4.1 started by root, uid 0
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.debug dhcpd: ip reservation not enabled
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Listening on Socket/br1/192.168.169.0/24
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Sending on   Socket/br1/192.168.169.0/24
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jan  1 00:00:38 localhost daemon.debug dhcpd: subnet mathes LAN0, enable IP RESERVATION
Jan  1 00:00:39 localhost daemon.debug dhcpd: ip-reservation write lease hw(b8:8d:12:1a:30:58),ip(192.168.2.53)
Jan  1 00:00:39 localhost daemon.debug dhcpd: ip-reservation write lease hw(20:64:32:c2:88:b2),ip(192.168.2.19)
Jan  1 00:00:39 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Wrote 2 leases to leases file.
Jan  1 00:00:39 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Listening on Socket/br0/192.168.2.0/24
Jan  1 00:00:39 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: Sending on   Socket/br0/192.168.2.0/24
Jan  1 00:00:39 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 192.168.2.18 via br0
Jan  1 00:00:39 localhost daemon.info dhcpd: DHCPACK to 192.168.2.18 (b8:8d:12:1a:30:58) via br0
Jan  1 00:00:29 localhost daemon.info dnsmasq[685]: started, version 2.58 cachesize 150
Jan  1 00:00:42 localhost daemon.warn dnsmasq[685]: overflow: 5 log entries lost
Jan  1 00:00:44 localhost daemon.info dnsmasq[1047]: started, version 2.58 cachesize 150
Jan  1 00:00:44 localhost daemon.info dnsmasq[1047]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n DHCP TFTP no-conntrack no-IDN
Jan  1 00:00:44 localhost daemon.info dnsmasq[1047]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Jan  1 00:00:44 localhost daemon.info dnsmasq[1047]: using nameserver XX.XXX.XXX.99#53
Jan  1 00:00:44 localhost daemon.info dnsmasq[1047]: using nameserver XX.XXX.XXX.97#53
Jan  1 00:00:45 localhost cron.info crond[1064]: crond: crond (busybox 1.18.5) started, log level 8
Feb  8 08:14:25 localhost user.info wanstatus: Internet Status: Connected
Feb  8 08:14:25 localhost user.info wanstatus: PING Success
Feb  8 08:14:29 localhost cron.err crond[1064]: time disparity of 6893773 minutes detected
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

**Please note I have XXX some of the ip address above but they both have a similar address just the last two numbers were different.**

Comment: dino Yesterday I tried the port forwarding for hosting my iis8 on internet and got this problem http://superuser.com/questions/548342/cant-open-dwr-112-router-configuration

Comment: In order to diagnose this problem you really want to show traffic dumps (ie TCP dumps) of the traffic leaving and entering the various interfaces.   Also, knowing the IP address and netmask of each device, and where you are testing from would be useful.  One possibility is an incorrectly set netmask on the on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks @david the problem has been the router's firewall not wot working properly, notified Belkin who verified the problem. Switched to a different router and all is working well now.